# R identifying a row prior to a change in sign

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
df <- c(5,9,-8,-7,-1)
```

How can I identify the position prior to a change in sign?
ie `df[2]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is pretty simple, if you know about the `sign` function...

```
which(diff(sign(df))!=0)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: ...and if you know about the `diff` function :)

Comment: Be careful, this answer considers c(0,1) to have a sign change. This may or may not be desired depending on the application!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Joshua's answer, but here's an alternative, more complicated one just for fun:

```
head(cumsum(rle(sign(df))$lengths),-1)
```

Comment: similarly to the above answer by @JoshuaUlrich, this answer considers c(0,1) to have a sign change. This may or may not be desired depending on the application!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be a terrible person, you could always use a for loop:

```
signchange <- function(x) {
    index = 0
    for(i in 1:length(x))
    {
        if(x[i] < 0)
        {
            return (index)
        }
        else
        {
            index = index + 1
        }
    }
    return (index)
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvote but if you're going to be a terrible person and use a loop you should at least check whether the first element is positive or negative.  The function as is detects the first negative value - not the first sign change.